# behaviour of signal handler when multiple signals are sent

Tags: c, signals

I am dealing with some issue, I have a function that's handling a signal and like that:

```
void sigChld(int noSig)
{
//some action here
}

void F1 () // some child process
{
struct sigaction action;
.... // initialisation of the structure with sigChld as the function handler
sigaction(SIGCHLD, &action, 0);

while(1)
callToFunction();
}
```

In my child process F1, I am attaching the handler to SIGCHLD to sigChld() and then I do callToFunction() that creates another process and do some treatment. At the end of its execution, It sends me a SIGCHLD which I need to treat in my handler.

Now my question is : I need the return value of callToFunction() so I thought about using a waitpid in the handler of sigchld before doing some actions. But what if during waitpid() or the actions, callToFunction() send another signal ? will the current handler stop ? or will continue its execution and then treat the next signal ?

In my problem, I need to treat completely the signals one after another one like if I was executing the handler in parallel.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure it's actually possible for a waitpid() in a SIGCHLD handler to get interrupted by a signal, since it should return instantly if there's a child available, but in general signals can occur during a signal handler just like anywhere else.